# Create an installer that requires a deb, node, and python packages

Tags: package-management, deb

I have written a python GUI application that requires gtk and python 2.7 (which can be installed using apt), and a node module (which can be installed using npm).

I know that each one of them has its own packaging system and its own installation system, but how can I put all of these in one package? As in be able to `sudo apt-get install mypackage` or `dpkg -i mypackage.deb`, and it would install all the dependencies automatically?

I've read about makefiles, setup.py, but I do not see how I can combine deb, node and python together.

Comment: Does the distribution you use have a package for the node module you want to use? If so, you just need to add a dependency on it.

Comment: Can you describe how can I do that? I believe it is just an npm module, no distribution package.